# Need to unload (re-initialise) a previously existing Howl (Howlerjs) every time a new array is passed

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3, media

I'm using howlerjs (https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js) to play sequentially a random array of 12 mp3 files.
I need to reinitialise the `howl` each time the new array is passed every time I run my `randomise()` function. 
There's a `unload()` method but I'm unable to make it work.
Could anyone please help?
Here's the code:

```
// Constants
// Multidimensional array with all (unique) filenames in their columns
const fileName = [
  ["a01", "b01", "c01", "d01", "e01", "f01"],
  ["a02", "b02", "c02", "d02", "e02", "f02"],
  ["a03", "b03", "c03", "d03", "e03", "f03"],
  ["a04", "b04", "c04", "d04", "e04", "f04"],
  ["a05", "b05", "c05", "d05", "e05", "f05"],
  ["a06", "b06", "c06", "d06", "e06", "f06"],
  ["a07", "b07", "c07", "d07", "e07", "f07"],
  ["a08", "b08", "c08", "d08", "e08", "f08"],
  ["a09", "b09", "c09", "d09", "e09", "f09"],
  ["a10", "b10", "c10", "d10", "e10", "f10"],
  ["a11", "b11", "c11", "d11", "e11", "f11"],
  ["a12", "b12", "c12", "d12", "e12", "f12"]
];

// Variables
let randomSelection = [];
let sequence = [];

// Functions
// Randomise array
function randomise() {
  sequence = fileName.map(option => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    return option[random];
  });
  randomSelection = sequence.map(createURL);
  function createURL(fileName) {
    return `assets/audacity/${fileName}.mp3`;
  }
  defineSong();
  console.log(randomSelection);
}

function createSequence(bars) {
  let allHowls = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= bars; i++) {
    let howl = new Howl({
      src: [randomSelection[i]],
      loop: false
    });
    allHowls.push(howl);
  }
  return allHowls;
}

function defineSong() {
  let isPlaying = false;
  let soundFiles = [];
  if (soundFiles.length) {
    soundFiles.forEach(sound => {
      sound.unload();
    });
  }
  soundFiles = createSequence(12);
  // using var because let isn't in scope
  for (var i = 0; i < soundFiles.length - 1; ++i) {
    soundFiles[i].on(
      "end",
      (function(i) {
        return function() {
          soundFiles[i + 1].play();
        };
      })(i)
    );
  }
  soundFiles[i].on("end", function() {
    isPlaying = false;
  });
  handlers(isPlaying, soundFiles);
}

// Event Listeners
// Grid play event
$(".bar").on("click", function() {
  let id = this.id;
  let barPath = `assets/music/${id}.mp3`;
  let bar = new Audio(barPath);
  bar.play();
});

// Randomise event
$("#btn-randomise").on("click", randomise);

// Play & Pause event
function handlers(playing, soundFiles) {
  let playButton = $("#play-minuetto"),
    pauseButton = $("#pause-button");
  playButton.on("click", function() {
    if (!playing) {
      isPlaying = true;
      soundFiles[0].play();
    }
  });
  pauseButton.on("click", function() {
    if (playing) {
      isPlaying = false;
      soundFiles[0].stop();
    }
  });

}

// Calls randomise() on load to have a valid array in case
// playSong() is called from the page before randomising
randomise();


$(window).on("load", defineSong);
```